# Soft deleting with backbone

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

It's not uncommon to mark something as deleted instead of really deleting it.

What's the best process to support such delete?

1. `model.save({deleted: True})`
2. `model.destroy()` 
   override tastypie's delete_detail to return data
   change backbone to expect a returning data
3. use `Backbone.emulateHTTP(`) so that `model.destroy()` actually sends PUT

Comment: 4. Override `delete_detail`, don't return data. No need to return data of deleted object.

Comment: use `model.clear()` which clear the data and will fire an event as well

Comment: @kroolik: I'm actually showing "message deleted" message for a deleted post.

Comment: @eugene, still - you don't need to receive any data from the `DELETE` request. If it succeeds, mark the post on client side as deleted, if you fetch the list of posts somewhere else, just return the correct data for deleted object in the returned list.